# What is the purpose of conversion-service and content-negotiation-manager in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

What is the purpose of `conversion-service` and `content-negotiation-manager` in Spring? We have this in our Spring appContext but I am not sure about its purpose.

---

For `content-negotiation-manager`:

I have read here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-content-negotiation that the content-negotiation-manager acts like a 'resolver' for `@RequestMapping` - e.g. if my mapping URL is "/person/create" - it will be called when the client accesses /person/create.json and /person/create.html (given the configuration below).

I am also able to access /person/list.xml and it returns an xml result even if xml is not defined in the `content-negotiation-manager` since I have the Jackson in my classpath:

> For file extensions in the request URI, the MVC Java config and the
>   MVC namespace, automatically register extensions such as .json, .xml,
>   .rss, and .atom if the corresponding dependencies such as Jackson,
>   JAXB2, or Rome are present on the classpath.

So, we defined the `content-negotiation-manager` since we support html, and it is not mapped by default. Is my understanding correct?

---

For `conversion-service`:

In our classes, we have an `ObjectMapper.readValue(json, Obj.class)` and `@RestController` returning an object in xml/json format depending on the request (it returns an xml format if you access /list.xml and returns json format when you access /list.json). But I've read that @RestController can work without the conversion-service. So I am not sure why it is supplied in the `<mvc:annotation-driven>`

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"/>

  <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />

  <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json"/>
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the conversion service and the content negotation manager are **always** used by Spring MVC, regardless whether you define them or not. You can configure them according to your needs. That's the case here.

E.g. `name="defaultContentType" value="application/json"` means that if the client doesn't prefer a specific media type the server should send back JSON.